# Displaying caught errors outside of IDE - overkill/critique?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, error-handling, flash-cs3

I have devised the following method for catching errors throughout my AS3 applications:

In the Document class, define the following methods:

```
//This is the handler for listening for errors
protected function catchError(event:ErrorEvent):void 
{ 
  displayError('Error caught: ' + event.text);
}

//Creates a MovieClip with a TextField as the child.
//Adds the MC to the stage
protected function displayError(msg:String):void
{
  var errorMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
  errorMC.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
  errorMC.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
  errorMC.graphics.endFill();

  var errorTxt:TextField = new TextField();
  errorTxt.multiline = true;
  errorTxt.width = stage.width;
  errorTxt.height = stage.height;
  errorTxt.selectable = true;
  addChild(errorMC);
  addChild(errorTxt);

  errorTxt.text = 'Error(s) Caught: \n' + msg;
}
```

To deal with classes that are used within the Document class I add the following so that I can register the previously mentioned functions:

```
protected var errorCatcher:Function;
protected var displayError:Function;

public function setErrorDisplayer(f:Function):void
{
  displayError = f;
}

public function setErrorCatcher(f:Function):void
{
  errorCatcher = f;
}
```

Now, I can display errors in the SWF at runtime, when testing the application in the browser.

For example:
(I didn't test the following it's just an example)

```
//Document class
package com
{
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import flash.event.ErrorEvent;
  import flash.text.TextField;
  import com.SomeClass;

  public class Document extends MovieClip
  {
    protected var someClass:SomeClass = new SomeClass();

    public function Document():void 
    {
      someClass.setErrorCatcher(catchError);
      someClass.setErrorDisplayer(displayError);
    }

    protected function catchError(event:ErrorEvent):void 
    { 
      displayError('Error caught: ' + event.text);
    }

    protected function displayError(msg:String):void
    {
      var errorMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
      errorMC.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
      errorMC.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
      errorMC.graphics.endFill();

      var errorTxt:TextField = new TextField();
      errorTxt.multiline = true;
      errorTxt.width = stage.width;
      errorTxt.height = stage.height;
      errorTxt.selectable = true;
      addChild(errorMC);
      addChild(errorTxt);

      errorTxt.text = 'Error(s) Caught: \n' + msg;
    }
  }
}
```

Is this overkill or am I missing a "best practice" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use FireBug to Debug and output from a SWF in the browser. Just Google for "firebug as3", and you will see a ton of people are doing this.

You can also use something like [De MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/). It has a lot of great features. For an overview, check out [Lee Brimlows De MonsterDebugger video from GoToAndLearn](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=109).

Comment: Perfect! MonsterDebugger is my new best friend.

Comment: Yeah it is really great. I have noticed that it seems to slow down the FPS significantly sometimes, depending on what's going on. But other than that, it's great. Also FlashDevelop's profiler is my new best friend :)